# Upload multiple files with metadata in one POST request

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, multipartform-data

I want to upload multiple files with related metadata in a single POST request.
Here's my POJO for that:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Attachment {
  private MultipartFile file;
  private String name;
  private String description;
}
```

I tried to upload the file with Postman using formdata (i.e. multipart/form-data), but it throws an exception saying the parameter attachment is not found.
I tried `@ModelAttribute` as well, but it fetches a blank list. When I tried with `@RequestPart` it threw this error: `"Required request part 'attachments' is not present"`

Here's my controller method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "attachments", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    public void addAttachment(@RequestPart List<Attachment> attachments) {
       // do something
    }
```

We can do this by sending a raw json with base64 encoded file, but I'd like to know how this can be done using multipart. I have followed many questions on StackOverflow, but none of the solutions did work.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Lakshmikant Deshpande

Unfortunately, it is currently not possible to upload multiple files with parameters in one request.
For details, please refer to source code '**RequestPartMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument()**'.